# New GFCI won’t work

Tags: kitchens

I have a kitchen outlet that I’m trying to install a GFCI. I’ve identified the line wires and load wires. The black line wire is hot. I connected the line wires to the appropriate terminals. I connected the load wires to their appropriate terminals. I do not have any power to the outlet. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you connect to the LINE terminals, not the LOAD terminals?

Comment: Did you turn your breaker back on?

Comment: What other locations are you trying to GFCI-protect?  Have you identified them and are you applying the sticker?  If that all went over your head, then do not use the LOAD screws, just attach all wires to LINE.  *Note the GFCI has a feature that accepts 2 wires under each screw.*

Comment: Remove any extra wires from the load connectors... when you're testing an outlet that doesn't work, start at the beginning to make sure it isn't a bad outlet... if you have hot wire to hot screw and neutral wire to neutral screw on the GFCI and nothing else, and you've checked the wire with a voltage tester to make sure the wires are hot, then you probably have a bad GFCI device and need to buy a new one. Can you take a photo of the outlet pulled out of the box a bit with wires connected so we can see if we can spot the problem?

Comment: Have you actually pressed test and reset many GFCI receptacles are shipped in the tripped state and require a test and reset to activate them.

Comment: How did you identify hot? Non-contact tester or voltmeter?

Answer (score 1):

GFCI connections (like many other things) work best when handled step-by-step:

1. Identify the Wires

You should have one set of wires (either a cable or wires together in a conduit) that is the *incoming power* and another (can be more than one) that is connecting to other ("load", "downstream") devices.

If you are not 100% certain which wires are the incoming power:

- Turn off the breaker.
- Disconnect **all** the wires from the GFCI receptacle and arrange them so that the can be tested separately
- Turn on the breaker
- Use a non-contact tester to identify the one **hot** wire
- The white (or gray, but usually white) wire that is paired with the hot wire is the neutral wire for incoming power

2. Connect **only** the incoming power

- Turn off the breaker
- Connect the hot incoming power to the hot *line* connection on the GFCI receptacle
- Connect the neutral incoming power to the neutral *line* connection on the GFCI receptacle
- All grounds from all cables/conduits (unless metal conduit and no ground wires) go together and to the GFCI receptacle
- Turn on the breaker and test the GFCI. If it still does not work, **stop** and ask more questions.

3. Connect the *other* wires

- Turn off the breaker
- All black or other wires that are not white/gray/green/bare go to the hot *load* connection
- All white or gray wires go to the neutral *load* connection
- Ideally you should work on one cable/conduit/group of wires at a time for easier trouble-shooting
- Turn on the breaker

If the GFCI works then try devices in the downstream receptacles. If you have problems at this stage then there is likely a miswired downstream receptacle, and that needs to be fixed as it is a danger waiting to happen.

Connecting everything to line instead of load is a workable solution in some cases. However, if the downstream receptacles are in locations that require GFCI protection (kitchen, bathroom, outside) then you really *want* to have them on "load".

Answer (score 1):

GFCI receptacles come “tripped” from the factory. Did you reset it after applying power?